# EF core , Code First Table rename not detected for migration definition, Scafolder is empty

Tags: ef-code-first, migration, entity-framework-core

I get empty migration builder when I change a class name in EF core.

In older EFs , it usually auto generate the code for renaming tables.

But not working in EF core

```
public class EventComment : Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual EventComment Parent { get; set; }

    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public virtual EventMaster EventMaster { get; set; }

}

public class Comment
{
    public string CommentTitle { get; set; }

    public string CommentDetails { get; set; }

    public int UpVoteCount { get; set; }
    public int DownVoteCount { get; set; }
    public int CommentEmotion { get; set; }

    public string CommentedByID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

now changing EventComment to CommentMaster. The migration is empty.

I use fluent API for configuring

```
        builder.Entity<EventComment>()
            .HasOne(e => e.EventMaster)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.EventID);

        builder.Entity<EventComment>()
            .HasOne(e => e.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.CommentedByID);

        builder.Entity<EventComment>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Parent)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the EF Core default table mapping [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables) (highlights are mine):

> By convention, each entity will be setup to map to a table with the **same name as the DbSet<TEntity> property** that exposes the entity on the derived context. If **no DbSet<TEntity> is included** for the given entity, the class name is used.

I guess this is different from the previous EF. The essential part is that although you renamed the entity class, if you keep the old `DbSet` property name, the table name will not change.